# how to stop a user reducing an integer input to less than 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, simple-form

I have a simple form integer input and i wan't to stop the user from being able to reduce the amount below 1 when clicking on the arrows in the input (to the right).

Is this possible without javascript? The only information i can find is adding the `min` attribute to the input but that does not work.

`<%= f.input :quantity, as: :integer %>`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this](https://newbedev.com/min-value-for-input-in-simple-form) should help you out.

In your case, try:

```
<%= f.input :quantity, as: :integer, input_html: { min: '0' } %>
```

More reading: https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form